# Lightning with Lighting Spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit, light, lightning

I am learning Spritekit and I would like to know how I can convey the impression of lightning by lighting up the scene. I DON'T want to show the actual lightning bolt. But I want the clouds in the sky (for example) lighting up, or the entire scene (followed by appropriate sounds) to convey a lightning effect during stormy weather.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way I believe you could do this is by creating an if statement and the changing the color to white then back to it's form. Also, a new zPosition would be needed if everything would be lite up.

```
if lightUpThePlace = true {

background.color = SKColor.white

background.zPosition = 100

//and then do either  : (Because the language is read top to bottom)

background.color = SKColor.//the regular color

background.zPosition = //default zPosition

}
```

Otherwise, you could make a white sprite node big enough for the screen and move it to the center instantly and then have it despawn.

```
let flash = SKSpritenode(imageNamed: "//white sprite node")

let move = SKAction.moveTo...

let despawn = flash.removeFromParent()

let sequence = SKAction.sequence([move, despawn])
```

Hope This Helped!

Comment: Hello, Thank you so so much for your suggestion. I will try this out and get back to you.